# Determine the mathematical expectation of the number of penalties

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a football game team A and B kick penalty until one of them scores a goal and the other - no. The probability that the goalkeeper from team A will drop the ball is $0.9$, and the probability that the goalkeeper from team B will drop the ball is $0.8$. Determine the mathematical expectation of the number of penalties.

Comment: Hint: Compute the probability that the game ends in $n$ rounds.

Comment: Checking if I understood the problem correctly - in each round both teams get to kick a penalty - the probability that team B scores is $0.1$ and the probability that team A scores is $0.2$, the game will end when in a round exactly one teams scored

Comment: @AsafRosemarin: Yes, you got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $p$ the probability that in a round, exactly one team scores a goal.
Then, as we have a geometric distribution, the exepcted number of rounds is $\frac{1}{p}$, or $\frac{2}{p}$ penalties.
It is not difficult to see that $$p=0.1\cdot 0.8 + 0.9 \cdot 0.2 = 0.26$$
As we must have that $B$ scores and $A$ doesn't ($0.1\cdot 0.8$) or that $A$ scores and $B$ doesn't ($0.2\cdot 0.9$).
Thus, the expected number of penalties is $\frac{2}{p}\thicksim 7.692$